# Write output of subprocess launched by a `screen` CLI Command to a log file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logging, stdout

I am launching a bunch of the same script (`generate_records.php`) into screens. I am doing this to easily parallelize the processes. I would like to write the output of each of the PHP processes to a log file using something like `&> log_$i` (StdOut an StdErr).

My shell scripting is weak sauce, and I can't get the syntax correct. I keep getting the output of the screen, which is empty.

Exmaple: `launch_processes_in_screens.sh`

```
max_record_id=300000000

# number of parallel processors to run
total_processors=10

# max staging companies per processor
(( num_records_per_processor = $max_record_id / $total_processors))

i=0
while [ $i -lt $total_processors ]
do
  (( starting_id = $i * $num_records_per_processor + 1 ))
  (( ending_id = $starting_id + $num_records_per_processor - 1 ))
  printf "\n  - Starting processor #%s starting at ID:%s and ending at ID: %s" "$i" "$starting_id" "$ending_id"
  screen -d -m -S "process_$i" php generate_records.php "$starting_id" "$num_records_per_processor" "FALSE"
  ((i++))
done
```

Comment: Why are you using `screen`?  Why not  just use normal shell i/o redirection to send the output to a file?  (`php generate_records.php "$starting_id" "$num_records_per_processor" "FALSE" > log-for-$start_id.txt 2>&1 &`)

Comment: I'm using `screen` to launch a bunch of the same script in parallel. I think your command will work fine, but I can't get it to work in context of the `screen` command. It's a `screen` command or sh syntactical issue I'm struggling with I think.

Answer (score 0):

If the only reason you're using `screen` is to launch many processes in parallel, you can avoid it entirely and use `&` to [start them in the background](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-command-line-run-in-background/):

```
php generate_records.php "$starting_id" "$num_records_per_processor" FALSE &
```

You may also be able to remove some code by using [`parallel`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel).